# Java equivalent of PHP str_word_count?

Tags: java, php, word-count

**Note**: I'm not looking for a word counting algorithm in Java here. I'm asking where to find `str_word_count` in the PHP source code.

I'm looking to recreate (*verbatim, line by line if possible*) the [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) PHP function as a Java method:

```
public class PhpWordCounter {
    public int strWordCount(String str) {
        // The exact algorithm used in PHP's str_word_count here...
        // The str_word_count method takes an optional parameter
        // "format", which, if 0, returns the number of words.
        // This is the portion of the routine that I will actually
        // be mimicking.
    }
}
```

I just downloaded PHP 5.3.23's source code (tarball) and extracted. I grepped for `str_word_count` and did not find anything, so I'm not even sure what to look for, let alone what file to search in. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the return type would definitely ***not*** be an int, if your goal is *exact* replication.

Comment: Good catch @Perception (+1) - I should have mentioned that the `format` is treated as 0 by default (so return the number of words as an integral type). So I'm not going to worry about any part of `str_word_count` that deals with any other `format` type.

Comment: the PHP source code is available, written in C. If you want to replicate the exact algorithm, that's where to start.

Comment: Right, but like I said I looked for `str_word_count` and didn't find it...

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - it looks like the implementation is in php-5.x.xx/ext/standard/string.c. Or at least part of it. Have you considered using [Apache Commons Lang 3 StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)? It has a `countMatches` method that already does this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should look better :) It should be available in the latest stable branch http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'str_word_count' {} \;

./ext/standard/php_string.h
./ext/standard/tests/strings/str_word_count1.phpt
./ext/standard/tests/strings/str_word_count.phpt
./ext/standard/basic_functions.c
./ext/standard/string.c
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a ready made function...
but:
split the string by spaces into an array
get the length of the array

String vals[] = myString.split("\s+");
int wordCount = vals.length;

Comment: Thanks but please see my update - I'm not asking for a Java word counting algorithm. I'm asking where to find str_word_count in the PHP source code.